# generate seemingly random unique numeric ID in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to use SQL Server to generate *seemingly random* unique 8-digit *numeric* ID (can pad zeros at front). Is there a built-in functionality for this? I saw [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28SQL.80%29.aspx) `Identity` property, but it is sequential, not random.

If this is not possible, is it good practice to directly write a randomly generated ID to db then check for exception? (note that my app is multi-threaded, so checking before writing doesn't guarantee uniqueness unless done in atomic action.)

Thanks!

UPDATE: Added "numeric" to clarify.
Edited to show that the randomness doesn't need to be cryptographically strong or anything near. Just seemingly random is good enough. Oliver suggested an elegant solution, and I've posted an answer using that approach. Thanks, Oliver!

Comment: Try `NewID()` inbuilt function

Comment: No inbuilt way (that I know of). The typical way to achieve this is to generate a list of all possible values beforehand, then randomly select one and remove it from the list.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with this id, but the rowversion may suit your needs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier - That's 8 byte not 8 digit.

Comment: Maybe it must not be random, but only not *easy guessable*. Than this article about [the multiplicative inverse from Eric](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/) may help.

Comment: @Oliver - nice! Forgot about that. Yes, that might be the best approach.

Comment: @Oliver yes, i only need them to be "seemingly" random. your link might just be what i need. back to reading more...

Comment: If anybody is going to use the mentioned multiplicative inverse you should maybe also consider to store the real sequence number within the database (that could even be the PK identity column) and just do the calculation on a different level (maybe the controller, the view, etc.) to keep this stuff from the DB away and the index within the DB fast.

Comment: @dragon_cat: If you find it useful and it works, than answer (with a little bit more detail about how you implemented it) and accept it for yourself.

Comment: @Corak - sure, so what's the problem? 99999999 holds in 8 bytes.

Comment: @SimonMourier - yes, but not everything held in 8 bytes can be uniquely displayed in 8 digits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate unique random numbers using SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875588/generate-unique-random-numbers-using-sql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Randomness clashes with uniqueness, but there is an elegant solution suggested by @Oliver when the numbers only need to *appear* random, while an underlying order exists. From Erics' http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/, the main idea is that for given a pair of coprime, positive integers x and m, we can find a *multiplicative inverse* y where (x*y) % m == 1. This is very useful because given a database row ID z, we can map z to another integer by doing `encoded = (z*x) % m`. Now given this `encoded`, how can we get z back? Simple, `z = (encoded * y) % m` since `(x*y*z) % m == z` given z < m. This one-to-one correspondence guarantees uniqueness of the "encoded" while provides an apparance of randomness.

Note that Eric showed how to calculate this multiplicative inverse. But if you are lazy, there is [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dsri/modular-inversion-answer.php).

In my implementation, I just store the sequential ID of each row as it is. Then, each ID is mapped to another number, something simlar to the "InvoiceNumber" in the article. When the customer hands you back this "InvoiceNumber", you can map it back to its original database ID by using multiplicative inverse.

Below is a C# example of encoding and decoding sequence from 0 to 9.

```
public static void SeeminglyRandomSequence()
{   //use long to prevent overflow
    long m = 10; //modulo, choose m to be much larger than number of rows
    long x = 7; //anything coprime to m
    long y = 3; //multiplicative inverse of x, where (y*x) % m == 1
    List<long> encodedSequence = new List<long>();
    List<long> decodedSequence = new List<long>();
    for (long i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        long encoded = (i * x) % m;
        encodedSequence.Add(encoded);
    }

    foreach (long encoded in encodedSequence)
    {
        long decoded = (encoded * y) % m;
        decodedSequence.Add(decoded);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("just encoded sequence from 0 to {0}. Result shown below:", (m - 1));
    Debug.WriteLine("encoded sequence: " + string.Join(" ", encodedSequence));
    Debug.WriteLine("decoded sequence: " + string.Join(" ", decodedSequence));
}
```

The printed result is:

```
just encoded sequence from 0 to 9. Result shown below:
encoded sequence: 0 7 4 1 8 5 2 9 6 3
decoded sequence: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As you can see, each input is mapped to a unique output, and it's easy to reverse this mapping. In your application, you might want to start with 1 since 0 always maps to itself.

Just to show the "apparent randomness" for larger m, below are the first 10 mappings when m=100,000,000:

```
just encoded sequence from 1 to 10. Result shown below:
encoded sequence: 81654327 63308654 44962981 26617308 8271635 89925962 71580289 53234616 34888943 16543270
decoded sequence: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NEWID() to generate uniqueIdentifier data which always random and unique each time

To get 8 character you can use substring, left etc function.

```
select substring( cast( NEWID() as varchar(100)),0,8)
```

or new logic for uniqueness:- http://forums.asp.net/t/1474299.aspx?How+to+generate+unique+key+of+fixed+length+20+digit+in+sql+server+2005+

```
select Left(NewID(),4)+Right(NewId(),4)
```

you can use [random()](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-numbers.aspx) function for this too.

check this links:
[How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)

[How to get numeric random uniqueid in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847092/how-to-get-numeric-random-uniqueid-in-sql-server)

**Updated**
If you want to unique value int data-type and 8 character long. Good to make a identity column like below, which is good for 8 character length data means (10,000,000). But after that it gives you exception. So be carefull which logic you want.(Still I say, its bad idea). store as random value as above with more length so uniqueness comes.

```
create table temp (id numeric(8,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, value1 varchar ) --if you want do not stop after 8 character , give int datatype.

insert into temp values( 'a'), ('b'), ('c')

select * from temp

drop table temp
```

**Finally**

It's not guaranteed unique but it's hard to get duplicates with NEWID()(refer above link forums.asp.net)

Comment: This isn't 8-digit though.

Comment: @DeanOC - use `left function` to limit

Comment: yes, for guarantee of uniqueness with 8 digit will always not true, but NewID will always give you unique value, if you consider whole length.

Comment: @Ajay thanks for the reply. would you recommend writing to db and check for exception in a while loop? (assuming number of rows is much less than 100,000,000)

Comment: Using exceptions to control expected workflow is always a bad idea. At least check if the value exists in the table before you try to insert it.

Comment: means you want to check unique value in the db before save it? if yes, then 8 digit of random no. not ideal, you must need 32 character which NEWID() gives. Still if you want to unique, then I prefer Identity column with int datatype is better option which don't need to check whole table stuff, just check the max value which is so much faster in 100,000,000 no. of data.

Answer (score 0):

USE the below query to create 8 digit randow unique number.

```
SELECT CAST(RAND() * 100000000 AS INT) AS [RandomNumber]
```

To avoid exception while inserting of existing number into DB use below query.

```
IF NOT EXIST(SELECT UniqueColumnID FROM TABLENAME WHERE UniqueColumnID = @RandowNumber)
BEGIN
    --Insert query using  @RandowNumber.
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL function or procedure as follow:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GenerateRandomNo] 
(
@Lower INT  = 111111111,
@Upper INT = 999999999
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TempRandom FLOAT
DECLARE @Random NVARCHAR(128); 


-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT @TempRandom = RandomNo from RandomNo
SELECT @Random = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),CONVERT(INT,ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * @TempRandom + @Lower), 0)))

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = @Random)
BEGIN
    SELECT @TempRandom = RandomNo from RandomNo
    SELECT @Random = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),CONVERT(INT, ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * @TempRandom + @Lower), 0)))
END

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Random

END
```

And then call that function passing parameter if you want to generate random no with specific length or range.

Answer (score 0):

```
 --create
--   table Tbl( idx int)
   DECLARE
   @unique_id int  

 SET @unique_id=  ( SELECT ROUND( 89999999 * RAND(
                                                   ) + 10000000 , 0
                                  )
                    )            
IF not EXISTS( SELECT idx
             FROM tbl
             WHERE idx = @unique_id
         )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO  tbl( idx
                               )
        VALUES( @unique_id
              )

SELECT @unique_id, * FROM tbl
    END;

    --TRUNCATE TABLE tbl
```

Comment: i edit the query so each random number is stored in tbl and each 'lottery' is compared with the existing number in that table so you will get only number that was not lottery before