# NEWID() is generating bad format values in SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, uniqueidentifier, qsqlquery, newid

I'm generating unique identifier values using NEWID().
The problem is sometimes values are generating like "65687519-E612-4B86-A8D8-F44E53DD6EDC"
The first part of unique identifier value is all numeric characters(65687519).
This is creating some problem in HTML.
What is the way to solve the problem?
Still I couldn't resolve the issue. 
Anybody please help.

Comment: Then the problem is your code and not the `NEWID()` function.

Comment: I'm generating the value using NEWID().There is nothing to do with coding. @ juergen d

Comment: When you have a problem with the output then there is something wrong with your code right there. `NEWID()` returns always valid output.

Comment: I'm generating the value  using NEWID() inside a stored procedure. So I don't think there is nothing to do with coding @ juergen d

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like:

```
SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(5)) AS Bigint)) as UNIQUE_NUMERIC
```

don't hate google. google is your friend!
similar problems already posted & answered like 
[How to get numeric random uniqueid in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847092/how-to-get-numeric-random-uniqueid-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about the identifier and just want it to be unique you can prepend some predetermined string to it (which won't harm its uniqueness, of course). E.g.:

```
SELECT 'id' + CAST(newid() AS VARCHAR(36)) AS new_id
```